# Strange directories in /home

Tags: bash, files, ls, autocomplete, directory-structure

There are some strange directories appearing in /home (so far, maybe in other locations too).

These directories do *not* show up in `ls` but do with `bash`'s tab autocomplete, when doing things like `cd`.

The exact name of this mystery directory is `.directory`.

`ls` and `cd` fail on these directories.

P.S. There was more than one in /media, but they seem to have disappeared now.

UPDATE: Output of `ls -la /home`:

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root      root      4096 Jan  3 11:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root      root      4096 Jan  3 11:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x 25 bharadwaj bharadwaj 4096 Jan  8 22:58 bharadwaj
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root      root        44 Jan  3 11:13 .directory -> /etc/kubuntu-default-settings/directory-home
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88875/why-are-filenames-that-start-with-a-dot-hidden-can-i-hide-files-without-using-a).

Comment: Are you sure they are directores?  Please show the full output of e. g. `ls -la /home/`

Comment: No, I know about hidden files. It's just that I have never before seen that directory in /home. Previously (last 2 years) there was only one directory in /home, i.e. _my_ home directory.

Comment: This seems like [this long-standing bug report](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-941134.html) and/or [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-default-settings/+bug/81257), and is not a duplicate.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Does this serve any purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should be files not directories. They are created by the dolphin file browser in order to support per directory behavior of the file browser.

See [Here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=223&t=119876)