# Why do shell globs omit dot files by default?

Tags: shell, wildcards

1)

`echo *`

Only displays file names having [a-z, A-Z] but does not display files starting with .

For example `.bashrc` is not covered with shell glob `*`

2)

`echo .*` gives the expected output.

---

In first case, why does the shell glob does not include file names with dot?

Comment: For the why, see the history of it here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88875/why-are-filenames-that-start-with-a-dot-hidden-can-i-hide-files-without-using-a

Comment: Related: [What is the setting in bash for globbing, to control whether * matches dot files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40662/86440).

Comment: and you don't need to have letters in file names... `123` and `--` are valid file names and match the `*`

Comment: This is how hidden files do hide. Without it they couldn't be called hidden.

Comment: @VPfB there’s more to it than that, consider `ls` with no arguments for example.

Answer (score 6):

That’s just the way globbing works, by default (in general, not just in shells). As per the [`glob(7)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html):

> **Pathnames**
>
> [...]
>
> If  a filename starts with a '.', this character must be matched explicitly.  (Thus, `rm *` will not remove
> `.profile`, and `tar c *` will not archive all your files; `tar c .` is better.)

See also [the relevant section of POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03).

There are shell settings you can use to change this, or globbing modifiers in some shells that you can add to change the behaviour temporarily; see [What is the setting in bash for globbing, to control whether * matches dot files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40662/86440) for more details.