# hiding a file from sudo rm -rf * (or skipping)

Tags: permissions, rm, read, error-handling

I am trying to hide one new file from a script that contains '`sudo rm -rf *`' - I am wondering if I can do this without redoing the script/ if this is possible or not.

I have tried the following:

```
$ sudo chattr +i file.txt
```

*and*

```
$ sudo chattr +a file.txt
```

The later is closer to the functionality I am looking for i.e. `+a`

These work, however, they are not skipped during my script, rather immediately it errors `Operation not permitted...` and doesn't remove any others.

..My **desired result would be for it to be completely hidden or skipped from `sudo rm -rf *`**

Comment: I can't help but feel you're trying to solve the wrong problem. If it's a script, copy it or edit it directly to remove the `rm -rf *` component.

Answer (score 2):

By default, `*`’s expansion will ignore files starting with a `.`, so if you name your file in that manner, `sudo rm -rf *` won’t delete it:

```
touch .myfile
rm *
ls -a
```

See [Why do shell globs omit dot files by default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/360400/86440) for details.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, but it still deleting the file... Perhaps because it's in a directory; so then I tried ./Dir/.file.txt

Comment: I think the issue is I am wanting to do this in a non hidden, regular directory, that has other non-hidden files perhaps. i.e. /directory/.Dir/.file.txt <---------------------- is that possible

Comment: Yes, if it’s in a sub-directory, `*` will include `Dir` and all its contents will be deleted, including the hidden file. `.Dir` would work.